# distribution of the coordinates of the second eigenvalues of a large d-regular graph

Tags: co.combinatorics

in the paper "expander graphs with applications" an intriguing problem was posed 
Fix an integer $d ≥ 3$ and consider large random $(n, d)$-graphs.  What can be said about the distribution of the coordinates of $v_2$? Specifically, does $v_2$ tend to be uniformly distributed on the unit sphere (in which the
distribution of these coordinates is nearly normal)?

Does anyone know some advances on this problem?

Comment: The title is incomprehensible. You want the coordinate of the second eigenvector, and what paper are you referring to?

Comment: cleaned up formatting and retagged. I too find the combination of question and title hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check ou[t this preprint by Dimitriou and Pal](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.5306.pdf), and voluminous references therein.